# IO Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: I do have permissions?

Tags: python, file, permissions, copy

What I am trying to do, is take a .mp3 file from a folder within a folder. Multiple times.
Everything works perfect, except for when I try to copy file to a new folder (which already exists), and it gives: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

```
import os, shutil

def startup():  
    os.system("cls")  
    print "\n osu! Extractor."  
    print "\n Press ENTER to begin."  
    raw_input()  
    for basename in os.listdir('C:\Program Files (x86)\osu!\Songs'):  
        basename2 = ('C:\Program Files (x86)\osu!\Songs\\' + basename)  
        for song in os.listdir(basename2):  
            if song.endswith('.mp3'):  
                print song  
                raw_input()  
                shutil.copy(basename2, 'C:\Program Files (x86)\osu!\Extracted_Songs')  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    startup()
```

I know that I have access to copy it manually, and I am admin on my computer, so I have no clue why this is happening. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Run the script as admin. You might have to run `cmd.exe` as admin to do that.

Comment: You should use raw strings for paths, or use `os.path.join`

Comment: On newer Windows, if UAC is turned on, being an admin does not necessarily mean running every command with admin permissions. Running with admin permission would also require using "run as admin" (a bit like using `sudo` on UNIX) Are you doing that?

Comment: @Blender, you're right about having to run it through cmd, but could you tell me the instructions on how to do so? I've got as far as running python.exe.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid I'm new to Python, would you mind telling me instructions on how to do so? I've taken a look at the documentation of os.path.join, however most of it confused me. An example would be nice :P

Answer (score 2):

By default, programs are not given permission to write into `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`. Save the file somewhere else or grant your program the permissions (e.g. by running it as administrator).

*(shoutouts to Osu!)*

Comment: Also worth mentioning, I tried copying something else from items on the desktop (in a folder) to another folder on the desktop. I still get the same error, using the same code as above. :c